# ~ (tilde) not working in R

Tags: r

I am trying to test some code in R, but it keeps giving me an error that the tilde key (~) is an unexpected symbol?

Is there something that can be done to fix this?

This was one of the codes I was trying to run:

```
# kNN
set.seed(123)
fit.knn <-  train(job permanency~., data=dataset, method="knn", metric=metric, preProc=c("permanency rate", "job skills"), trControl=control)
```

and I get the following error

> Error: unexpected symbol in "fit.knn <-  train(job permanency"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with the tilde operator.  The unexpected symbol is the second word in what is presumed to be a syntactically invalid column name. If `job permanency` is the name of a column, you will need backticks around it because it is a non-standard name.  Try using

```
train(`job permanency` ~ ., ...)
```

But in general I would recommend using standard naming conventions (i.e. without spaces).  You can convert your current names to syntactically valid names with

```
names(dataset) <- make.names(names(dataset))
```

`job permanency` will become `job.permanency`, and backticks will no longer be required.